# How do I remove certain variables using select_if

Tags: r, dplyr

In the dataset three of the variables are of class list. Remove the list variables using the dplyr function select_if(), and save the resulting data set as starwars_. How do I do this?

Answer (score 0):

We may use `where` to find the `list` columns (`is.list`) and either `negate` or use `-`

```
library(dplyr)
df1 %>%
    select(-where(is.list))
```

-output

```
# A tibble: 3 × 1
   col1
  <int>
1     1
2     2
3     3
```

---

Or using the `starwars` data

```
data(starwars)
starwars %>% 
   dplyr::select(-where(is.list))
# A tibble: 87 × 11
   name               height  mass hair_color    skin_color  eye_color birth_year sex    gender    homeworld species
   <chr>               <int> <dbl> <chr>         <chr>       <chr>          <dbl> <chr>  <chr>     <chr>     <chr>  
 1 Luke Skywalker        172    77 blond         fair        blue            19   male   masculine Tatooine  Human  
 2 C-3PO                 167    75 <NA>          gold        yellow         112   none   masculine Tatooine  Droid  
 3 R2-D2                  96    32 <NA>          white, blue red             33   none   masculine Naboo     Droid  
 4 Darth Vader           202   136 none          white       yellow          41.9 male   masculine Tatooine  Human  
 5 Leia Organa           150    49 brown         light       brown           19   female feminine  Alderaan  Human  
 6 Owen Lars             178   120 brown, grey   light       blue            52   male   masculine Tatooine  Human  
 7 Beru Whitesun lars    165    75 brown         light       blue            47   female feminine  Tatooine  Human  
 8 R5-D4                  97    32 <NA>          white, red  red             NA   none   masculine Tatooine  Droid  
 9 Biggs Darklighter     183    84 black         light       brown           24   male   masculine Tatooine  Human  
10 Obi-Wan Kenobi        182    77 auburn, white fair        blue-gray       57   male   masculine Stewjon   Human  
# … with 77 more rows
```

#### data

```
df1 <- tibble(col1 = 1:3, col2 = list(1, 2, 3))
```